# Storyboard Preview do not match simulator or device in xCode 6

Tags: xcode, storyboard, ios8, xcode6

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time now, either I am stupid, or Apple hav just made this really tricky. Storyboard Preview do not match simulator or device in xCode 6! I have added constraints so that the app looks just fine in all screen sizes in preview but it looks messed up when I run it in the simulator or on my device. help!

do you need any screenshots to answer my question?

I know other people have had the same issue but I can not find any answers.

[image: my project, everything looks just fine]

[image: the simulator does not look fine (this happens when I run the app on my phone as well, and it happens to all screen sizes in the simulator as well)]

Comment: I suspect you are not looking at the "storyboard preview" - you are looking at the Canvas (the place where you design the interface, constraints, etc.). The Preview is the thing you see in the Assistant Pane, and it is usually a correct rendering of what you will see when the app runs.

Comment: Are there any warnings (red or yellow icon) in your Canvas? If so, that's the source of the problem. Keep working until there are no warnings. At that point, the canvas will be a good match for what you'll get when you run.

Comment: nope, I am looking at the preview (Main.storyboard(Preview)), not the storyboard itself. Wait a min I will post some pictures

Comment: Cool, thanks. It will help if we can see the canvas too.

Comment: now it is updated @matt

Comment: Can you post the project on github? That way I can grab it and explore it and play around with it.

Comment: ok, but you know whats wrong?

Comment: Obviously not. That is what I'm trying to find out. Do you want me to look at it or not?

Comment: yeah, wait a moment then for me to post it over there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62470/discussion-between-matt-and-b3rge).

Comment: May be this went wrong: e.g You are testing in iphone 4  on simulator but the device your storyboard size has inferred is iphone 5..

Answer (score 7):

The storyboard "Preview" doesn't match the simulator if you have any constraint errors/conflicts. I was having this problem, and found this question while searching for an answer. 
Once I got all of the conflicts resolved, the Preview worked. It seems like the preview should consistently show what the simulator would show to help during the setup, but it's all out of whack if there are conflicts.

Comment: Though I dont have any errors or conflicts in the canvas, the preview and simulator doesn't match. Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xcode 6.3.1 and I was having the same problem(s). What I discovered is that you are missing constraints... 
open main.storyboard in your "Structure" column you should see some red arrows, single click them and you should see what constraints you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm that this was resolved after taking care of all warnings and errors related to Auto Layout.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed my size class problem by having my constraints be set for compact width / regular height. When I set constraints specific to compact width / any height, it ignored my custom values.

Hope that helps. Took me forever to figure out because the description lead me to believe my custom layout would cover more devices with the latter choice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got the latest xcode installed. I had the exact same problem before realising there was an update waiting. Now I've installed the update my preview matches what appears on the simulator.

Comment: hi can you post a link to the update or tell me the steps to do so, I'm getting this same issue and i'm already on xcode 6.1

Answer (score 0):

How I got this fixed is by updating Xcode to the latest version. And then recreated the NIB/Storyboard files that were created using the previous version of Xcode. It started working. Weird fix :/

Comment: hi can you post a link to the update or tell me the steps to do so, I'm getting this same issue and i'm already on xcode 6.1

Comment: Delete the previous view controller and create it again. Should work.

Comment: I ran an update check, it says its up to date. Delete as in the first default VC? Because I'm getting this problem on almost all my VCs.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a constraints issue**. 
Some constraints are not set properly or not set at all. Once all constraint issues are resolved, you would see the simulator and preview matching exactly!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this issue in Xcode 8 and all all your constraints are in place (i.e. no warnings or errors) what solved it for me was **quitting** the simulator and restarting the app through Xcode again.